# How can I project a field that is inside an object in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm using "sample_mflix" database provided by mongo atlas and mongodb vs code extension to practice.
My code looks like this so far:

```
use('sample_mflix');

db.movies.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: 'comments',
      localField: '_id',
      foreignField: 'movie_id',
      as: 'comments'
    },
  },
  {$unwind: '$comments'},
  {  
    $project:{
      comments:'$comments',
      _id:0 
    }
  },
    {  
    $project:{
       name:'$comments.name',
       email:'$comments.email',
       date:'$comments.date',
    }
  },
])
```

And this is the result I get from it:

```
[
  {
    "name": "Taylor Scott",
    "email": "taylor_scott@fakegmail.com",
    "date": {
      "$date": "1970-11-15T05:54:02Z"
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "Jaqen H'ghar",
    "email": "tom_wlaschiha@gameofthron.es",
    "date": {
      "$date": "1981-11-08T04:32:25Z"
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "Yara Greyjoy",
    "email": "gemma_whelan@gameofthron.es",
    "date": {
      "$date": "2012-11-26T11:00:57Z"
    }
  }
.
.
.]
```

As you can see, the ***date*** field is an object in this document, but I want to bring  with $project only the  string value of the date  which is in the ***$date*** field, like this:

```
  {
    "name": "Yara Greyjoy",
    "email": "gemma_whelan@gameofthron.es",
    "date": "2012-11-26T11:00:57Z"
  }
```

How can I achieve it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `$toString`

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $set: {
      date: {
        $toString: "$date"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/UAzwWdA0LZG)